# Django filter from the model field

Tags: django

I want to make a filter on the site by author
for example, I made a language filter like this:

models.py

```
CATEGORIES = (
    (1, 'Russian'),
    (2, 'English')
)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    lang_category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORIES, default=1, db_index=True)
```

views.py

```
def index(request, tag_slug=None):
    books = Book.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    
    form = BookFilterForm(request.GET)
    filtered_queryset = BookFilter(request.GET, queryset=books)

    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['lang_category']:
            books = books.filter(lang_category__icontains=form.cleaned_data['lang_category'])
```

forms.py

```
class BookFilterForm(forms.Form):
    LANG_CHOICES = [
        ('', 'All languages''),
        (1, 'Russian'),
        (2, 'English')
    ]

    lang_category = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=LANG_CHOICES,  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}), label='Select a language')
```

this works for me, but there is another field that I want to filter by:

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    lang_category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORIES, default=1, db_index=True)
    **author_book = models.CharField(max_length=300)**
```

tell me how you can filter by this type of field

I tried this and of course it didn't work:
forms.py

```
author_book = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Book.author_book, required=False,  widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}), label='Author')
```

Comment: (1) You shouldn’t use a `CharField` for `author_book`. Create a new model `Author` and use either a `ForeignKey` (one author for one book)  or a `ManyToManyField` (many authors for one book). (2) Use the [select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) widget

Comment: the site is already working and if you do this with models, everything will break unfortunately
I don't know migration well enough to fix it.